# How to interrogate Glimpse saved requests?

Tags: debugging, asp.net-mvc-2, glimpse

Glimpse MVC debugger supports saving requests on the server. This is configured by the

`<glimpse enabled="true" requestLimit="15">` requestLimit configuration. The default being 15.

How do I access this information?

I'm having issues with a specific MVC controller action hanging, since it hangs I do not receive a page response back such that the Glimpse results will appear in browser. However I would assume this information should be available on the server due to the request history?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a controller somewhere in your site that works and you have a view that uses that controller that you can see Glimpse on, the remote tab should work really well in this case.

The remote tab is essentially a window to those 15 stored requests on your server. The remote tab is designed to be an interface that allows you to view the stored information you are after.

Given this you should be able to go to the remote tab, select the named session which you where using (which is probably 'null' or empty or something similar if you haven't changed it) and then view the requests.

At that point you can load up the glimpse data for any one of those stored requests.

Let me know how you get on giving this a go.